# javascript puts out NaN and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal, nan

Well, I got this problem with my Javascript homework.  I need to make a binary translator and well Javascript does not really want me to...

It works but not really as it should...  If I declare the variable with a number, it works.  But if I use `document.getElementById` to make it some kind of interactive, then it does not want to work.  It just gives NaN.  I know that it means not a number, but I use the parseInt() and well it works without the `document.getElementById`...

So here is the code how it works:

```
var input = 15;
function convertdec()
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML 
        = "binary number: " + parseInt(input).toString(2);
}
```

The output is 1111, which is correct, BUT this is how it should also work and how I want it to be:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
function convertdec()
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML 
        = "binary number: " + parseInt(input).toString(2);
}
```

Tthe output of this should also be 1111 if you fill in 15 but it says:

binary number: NaN

If any one could help me, it would be really great!

### edit

ok, so there was asked for my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Binairy Converter</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="text" name="text" id="input" />
        <input type="button" id="conbin" onclick="convertbin()" value="bin to dec" />
        <p id="output" ><p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### edit

yeah i fixed the problem by doing:

```
var input;
function convertdec()
{
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "binary number: " + parseInt(input).toString(2);
}
```

but thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Try passing input to your function as an argument, or getting it from the element within the `convertdec` function.

Comment: How are you setting this code up to execute when the user types something in? Can you show the relevant piece of markup? Is there actually an element with id of `input`? Can you demonstrate the problem for us in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I like big "wat"s and I cannot lie;/JavaScript puts out `NaN` and I don't know why./So when I parse an int and its out is right/I think I see the light,/but then I get stuck when I parse markup/and the output has no luck./Deep in the code I'm writing/I notice too early citing/That eagerly captured `input.value`./Your homeboy's trying to warn you/Here's a blueprint: Capture later if you want an int.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing well to fetch the DOM elements outside the function as this DOM parsing is expensive and the DOM doesn't change, but you do need to fetch the values inside the function to get their current values, not the values on page load.  Try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
function convertdec()
{
    output.innerHTML = "binary number: " + parseInt(input.value, 10).toString(2);
}
```

Also note that `parseInt()` parses in octal if you have a leading zero, so asking it for "08" nets you "10".  Fix that by using `parseInt(num, 10)`.  I've made that mod in the above example too.

Comment: unfortunately the code that you proposed did not work at all. also when i added a semicolon at the end of the declaration of the var output.

maybe you have any other options?

Comment: Good catch on the missing `;`.  I've updated the answer.  This solution works just fine for me.  Perhaps post a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

This might be an artifact of how you displayed snippets... but it looks like you're setting input to whatever the value is when the page loads... you'd probably be better off doing

```
function convertdec()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "binary number: " + parseInt(input).toString(2);
}
```

so that the value gets set when the function gets called

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing this in context, here's what I suspect is occurring:

```
// you're getting the value from the textbox as it exists
// when the page is rendered: ""
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

// when you call this, it operates on value ... which is always ""
function convertdec()
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML 
        = "binary number: " + parseInt(input).toString(2);
}
```

One subtle change should fix it:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
function convertdec()
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML 
        = "binary number: " + parseInt(input.value).toString(2);
}
```

Addendum: As robrich notes in his answer, using `parseInt(input.value, 10)` will ensure the string in the textbox is interpreted as a base-10 number.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the problem is that you aren't selecting the correct element and hence the actual value in `input` isn't the string `"15"`.  The use of `input` itself as the ID is suspicious as it's a tag type and typically not an ID

Can you show us the HTML which declares `input`?